# Implementing Queues Using Linked Lists

Tags: java

I'm trying to understand how the add method works a ListQueue for revision. Any help will be much appreciated. I was unable to find any full explanations online and unfortunately can't get my head around it.

```
private Cell frontCell,backCell; 

  @Override
public void add(char x) {
   Cell newCell = new Cell(x);
    if(frontCell == null){
        frontCell = backCell = newCell;
    }else{
        backCell.next = newCell;
        backCell = newCell;
    }
}
```

There is also an inner class "Cell"

```
 public class Cell{

    char data;

    Cell next;

    public Cell(char data){
        this.data = data;
        next = null;
    }
}
```

"frontCell" stores the Cell at the beginning of the queue and "backCell" stores the Cell at the back.

"frontCell" references to "backCell" which contains the data that just got added. Then if another character is added "backCell.next = newCell" and "backCell = newCell".

How are the cells in-between the front and back cells in the queue stored?

How does the referencing work with "frontCell" being set to "backCell"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not an expert but I will try to explain the way I understand it.

When you create your queue it is empty, so it means that the front cell and the back cell, both are null.

Then when you add a new cell (Cell 1)

```
Cell newCell = new Cell(x)
```

the new cell stores the value `x` and its next cell is null because you haven't inserted between front and back, then it enters the if because as I said your frontcell is null

```
if(frontCell == null){
    frontCell = backCell = newCell;
}
```

Here the new cell is both the front and the back and its next cell is null because there is no other items.

When you add another cell (Cell 2) this time the if code is not triggered because front is not null anymore so the code executed is

```
backCell.next = newCell;
    backCell = newCell;
```

Here the last cell (the only one you have) changes its next cell wich previously was null to point at the second cell and then reference to the cell at the back just change from the first to the second one. If you debug the code at this point you would have something like

```
firstcell= Cell1
Cell1.next= Cell2
Cell2.next = null
back = Cell2
```

And if you add another cell you would have

```
firstcell= Cell1
Cell1.next= Cell2
Cell2.next = Cell3
Cell3.next=null
back = Cell3
```

I hope this helps you undertand it better

Comment: In the else statement would this be the same? backCell.next = newCell;    backCell = backCell.next;

Comment: Thank you for everyone's help. Your answer I found made it suddenly click.

Answer (score 1):

Your Cell class has `data` for each cell, and `next`, which references the next cell in the list, and that is how they are all linked together.

`if(frontCell == null)` is asking if the list is empty, if so then `frontCell = backCell = newCell;`, which means that the new Cell you are adding is the only cell in the list, thus it is both the `frontCell` and also the `backcell`.

`else` if the list is not empty, `backCell.next = newCell;` the new cell you are adding is linked to by the `backCell`, and your newCell is the new backCell (`backCell = newCell;`).

It may be easier to try drawing out data structures like these on paper (like [this excellent free Data Structures textbook](http://opendatastructures.org/ods-java/3_1_SLList_Singly_Linked_Li.html) shows), and try adding and remove a few cells, following what the code tells you is happening.

Comment: Okay this is making things clearer. When you want to remove the front of the queue (for the removeFront() method not shown) you set "frontCell = frontCell.next". This makes sense as you are removing the front and replacing it with the next item that references to the others in the queue. But at what point in the program is frontCell.next ever set? The add method only changes the backCell.

Answer (score 0):

The line `frontCell = backCell = newCell` is only triggered when `frontCell` is null, i.e. when the queue is **empty**. This make sense -- when you add an element to a 0-element queue, it becomes a 1-element queue, so front and back cells are the same.

If there are already cells in the queue, the last element in the queue has its next pointer point to the newest addition, and then the new addition is set to the back.

Empty Queue:

```
 []
 /\
f  b
```

Adding one element

```
[E1]
 /\ //front and back are pointing
f  b
```

Multi-element queue before add:

```
[E1->E2->E3->(null)]
 /        \
f          b
```

After Add:

```
[E1->E2->E3->E4-null]
 /            \
f              b
```